# Issue with armature deformation

Tags: mesh, rigging

So I've been working on a project in which I need to rig multiple characters. I downloaded Fuse off Steam as a quick character generator, I tried MakeHuman but I didn't like the realism. I used the website to equip my character mesh with a basic rig and imported it as a .fbx into Blender. When posing the mesh I realised a deformation occurring at the joints of my mesh, the mesh would curve and deform at an odd angle creating a unnatural appearance where the bend would appear to shrink slightly before returning to its original shape. I tried applying automatic weights and this failed either distorting the mesh to an unrecognisable ammount or disconnecting the parent altogether.
If anyone has any advice as to a way I could fix it or a better character generator with automatic weighting and rigging I would very much appreciate the help.

[image: Image of deformed pose]

Comment: It looks like you don't have enough geometry in your mesh to facilitate the bend properly. Try subdividing it and then rebind (might need a smooth modifier after subdividing). You may also need to do more weight painting, but try the denser mesh without it first and see what happens.

Comment: By the way, Makehuman is a great tool and shouldn't necessarily be panned just because it doesn't generate cartoon proportions on the fly. You can convert a Makehuman model to a cartoony version fairly quickly with sculpting tools (don't use dyntopo). May still be easier than modeling from scratch. Makehuman's topology is quite good and tends to produce decent joint deformations.